# Passing -I pattern through multiple xargs

Tags: grep, sh, xargs

I have a list of files

```
$ls
reads_string1
reads_string2
reads_string3
```

I want to search and count the occurrences of `string1` in `reads_string1`, `string2` in `reads_string2` and `string3` in `reads_string3` on lines 2, 6, 10, ..., N of each of the respective files (hence the use of awk below)

To do this I want to be able to pass the xargs pattern through two xargs.  Here is my current non-working "solution."

```
ls reads_* | cut -d"_" -f2 | xargs -I pattern awk '{if (NR % 2 == 0 && NR % 4 != 0){print}}' reads_pattern | xargs grep -Hc "^pattern" reads_pattern
```

Is there a way to pass through the pattern from the first xargs to the second xargs?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with only awk:

```
awk '{
      f=FILENAME;
      gsub('/^.*_/',"",f);
      if(FNR%4==2 && $0 ~ "^"f )
        {a[f]++
       }
      }
      END{
        for (i in a){
        print i,a[i]
        }
      }' reads_*
```

This will use awk buildin variable `FILENAME` and parse it to variable `f` to get the `string1`, `string2` etc.

Then if modulus 4 of `FNR` is equal to 2( which matches line numbers 2,6,10.....) and the line starts with `f`( which is `string1`, `string2` for currespnigng files),  value in array `a` with index as `f`  is incremented by 1.

At the end print the index as well as array with that index ie count.